# Do the upgrades in Lunar Racer help me be a better racer?

Tags: lunar-racer

The game doesn't really explain how the garage and the upgrades work. The upgrades seem to be mostly aesthetic (changing the look of my wheels or my nitro boost), but are they actually helpful?

What does each class of upgrades actually do for my vehicle?

Comment: Classic usability problem...devs should label their freaking options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless looking fly in your pimped out moon ride somehow leads to improved driving performance on your part (the euphoria gives you better reflexes or something or more likely a better colour scheme makes it easier to see and therefore you can react more quickly), **customizations in Lunar Racer do not make you a better racer.** To quote [a review of Lunar Racer](http://toucharcade.com/2012/01/11/lunar-racer-review/), "The customizations don't actually improve the attributes or performance of your vehicle, but it allows you to personalize its appearance."

**Each class of upgrades, Body, Canopy, Wheels and Nitro only change the appearance of your vehicle and do nothing else for it.** The offensive and defensive weapons on the other hand serve useful purposes.